# VBA code that can search through one row but multiple columns to find a specific value and list the locations of the value in a new cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code that looks through a row with 17 columns for a value of either "Y" or "y".  Once it finds the columns with "y" values I want it to write the column names of each location with a Y into a different cell.

I have tried multiple things such as an If Then Statement but this will only keep the last location that it finds a Y value and I would like a list of all of the locations.

I have string values in columns C through S that are either "Y", "y" or "N". I would like the result of where there is a "Y" or "y" to be placed in Column B.

```
    Sub FindLocation()
    Dim needs As Range, result as Range 'needs is the input value and result is where I would like the column names to be set to.

    'This is the first column, C, where there is input
    For I = 10 To 10  'Defines which row
    Set needs = Range("C").Cells(10, 1) 'Sets location of first possible "Y"
    Set result = Range("B").Cells(10, 1) 'Sets location of where to put column title
    If needs.Value = "Y" Then result = "C" 'If then statements stating what to put if a "Y" is found
    If needs.Value = "y" Then result = "C"
    If needs.Value = "N" Then result = ""
    Next I

    'Same as above just for the next column D.
    For I = 10 To 10
    Set needs = Range("D").Cells(10, 1)
    Set result = Range("B").Cells(10, 1)
    If needs.Value = "Y" Then result = "D"
    If needs.Value = "y" Then result = "D"
    If needs.Value = "N" Then result = ""
    Next I

    End Sub
```

Say the above code is run for the two columns listed and there is a Y in column C, D.  Right now only D would be shown in the results cell, B.

I would like for C and D to be printed into the results cell, B if there is a Y in both of them.

Comment: `I have tried multiple things...` Post your efforts here and we'll be happy to help you fix it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: @OP come on, we expected your added "effort" to, at least, make it easier to understand your requirement. Honestly and friendly, it made i even more difficult.

Comment: Simplified the code to make it more generic and added more information on my requirement.  Hopefully that helps make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For I = 10 To 10

This is looping between 10 & 10, so either the loop isn't needed or you need to change the start / end points. Also, you don't appear to be using the variable I in your code, so your For is always pointing to the same spot Cells(10,1).

- result = should probably be result.Value = to set the value of the cell to a particular value

Here is an example of looping through columns of row 2 of RangeTwo to find a Y, grabbing the value of RangeTwo row 1 and placing it in RangeOne in the same column:

```
For I = 1 To 10
    Set needs = Range("RangeTwo").Cells(2, I)
    Set result = Range("RangeOne").Cells(1, I)
    If needs.Value = "Y" Then result.Value = Range("RangeTwo").Cells(1, I)
    If needs.Value = "y" Then result.Value = Range("RangeTwo").Cells(1, I)
Next I
```